# When using Facebook external auth in Web API 2, email address isn't always returned in method response

Tags: c#, facebook, asp.net-web-api2

I'm using Web API 2 to authenticate a user with Facebook credentials. After calling

```
api/Account/ExternalLogins?returnUrl={returnUrl}&generateState={generateState}
```

and authenticating through Facebook, I call `api/Account/UserInfo`

to get the user's email and check if they have registered. I get a response message of

```
{"Email":"User's Full Name","HasRegistered":false,"LoginProvider":"Facebook"}
```

before I can call `api/Account/RegisterExternal`

The issue is that I need the user's email address to put in my request message body for the `RegisterExternal` method.

If I happen to know the user's email address and call `api/Account/RegisterExternal`, then call `api/Account/UserInfo`, it will display the user's email in the response message. Anyone seen this issue before?

Comment: Can you clarify if this is only happening for some users or all users?

Comment: So far, it seems to be myself and the other developers working on it.

Comment: I'm not 100% familiar with the framework but are you sure that the code is explicity requesting the `email` field when fetching the users info?

Comment: Though I've been working with it for a month or so now, I'm not 100% sure myself. I do know that in the Facebook developer site, I do ask that Facebook sends me that information for the user.

I've also read though that unless the user explicitly sets email as public, it won't necessarily send that info back. Lots of conflicting information I'm receiving.

Comment: To help clarify, the permissions you have been approved for on the developer site DOES NOT mean that this information will automatically be returned in a request to get the user information. What they do is allow you to ask the user to give you permission to access this information. The info you have read about the email not being returned is probably correct, generally he email field was not returned because the email might be missing (for example the user signed up with their phone number), it might be invalid or hasn't been confirmed yet.

Comment: Excellent point. I'm thinking the path of least resistance is to ask the user for their email address on the client after authentication. I have seen a few templates using this method.